# Binding with relative source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to understand how the `RelativeSource` works.

With the setup below I'd expect to see the text "I am the MainViewModel" displayed on the form, however I see an error in the debugger and no text on the `MainWindow`:

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='UnderstandingBindings.ViewModels.MainViewModel', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=SomeProperty; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='myText'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

I have a ViewModel like this:

```cs
class MainViewModel
{
    public string SomeProperty { get => "I am the MainViewModel"; }
    private readonly ChildViewModel _child = new ChildViewModel();
    public ChildViewModel Child => _child;
}

class ChildViewModel
{
    public string SomeProperty { get => "I am the ChildViewModel"; }
}
```

the MainWindow XAML looks like:

```xml
<Window x:Class="UnderstandingBindings.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UnderstandingBindings.Views"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:UnderstandingBindings.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel x:Name="pnlMain">
        <TextBlock x:Name="myText" Text="{Binding SomeProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The data context is assigned like this:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _viewModel = new MainViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = _viewModel.Child;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wpf looks for the Ancestors of the xaml element the binding is declared on. You can think of it as walking up the Visual Tree.

You'd use it to Bind to a property thats on that Ancestor or have to bind to a viewmodel by going through it's DataContext Property. So for example:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myText" Text="{Binding DataContext.Child.SomeProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

That only works if the DataContext is set to the MainViewModel in your example tho. If you want the Binding to go the direction you expected then you need to add a reference to the Parent Viewmodel on the Child.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of a [relative source within a binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=net-5.0) does the following.

> Gets or sets the binding source by specifying its location relative to the position of the binding target.

This means it sets the `Source` property of the binding to an element in the visual tree.  This can be the current element (`Self`) or an ancestor (e.g. `StackPanel` is an ancestor of the `TextBlock` it contains) or a templated parent in case of control templates. This depends on the [`Mode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode?view=net-5.0) that you set. A relative source allows you to specify a property path on that element in a binding, like its `DataContext` or `Tag` or any other property.

The error that you get translates to: *I searched for an instance of type `MainViewModel` in the visual tree starting from `TextBlock`. Then I checked the next ancestor `StackPanel`, which is not a `MainViewModel`. Then I checked the next ancestor `Window`, which is also not a `MainViewModel`. There is no other ancestor, so I could not find anything.*

You are misusing relative source here. View models are not part of the visual tree, but act as data context for elements. For your example using the data context the right way is enough. Once you set the data context on `MainWindow`, it is *inherited* in all child controls, if not specified otherwise, e.g. explicitly assigning a different data context on an element. Consequently, the `TextBlock`, which is a child of `MainWindow` will get the same data context that you assigned to the `DataContext` property of `MainWindow`.

The data context in your example is an instance of `ChildViewModel`, so in order to bind to its `SomeProperty`, you do not need a relative source binding, just a property path which is automatically resolved using the `DataContext` (which is set as the binding source) of the corresponding control.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myText" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
```

This will lead to the following text: *I am the ChildViewModel*

If you want to bind to the `SomeProperty` of `MainViewModel`, you should set the `DataContext` accordingly.

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.DataContext = _viewModel;
}
```

The binding in `TextBlock` is the same as above, if you want to display the `SomeProperty` of `MainViewModel`.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myText" Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
```

If you want to bind the `SomeProperty` of the `ChildViewModel` instead, you can change the path.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myText" Text="{Binding Child.SomeProperty}"/>
```

In both example, it will lead to the following text: *I am the MainViewModel*